# Mixing programming languages for the same project

Tags: python, sockets, node.js, programming-languages

Is it a bad idea to mix programming languages, for example have a `node.js` server that sends some stuff to a `python` program that then goes and does other stuff with it. This is pretty vague but what is the best way to send data between different programs, or is this just a terrible idea and I shouldn't even consider it? sockets?

Comment: Did you do any research on this? It's quite common to mix and match programming languages to play on each one's respective strengths. E.g., for a web application, I might be using PHP, JavaScript/jQuery,  and SQL all on the same page.

Comment: What OP asked that I think it was not answered, is how you can combine, make two processes that were programmed in different languages cooperate. That's why he referred to `sockets`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why this is harmful.  Polyglot programming is common these days: jQuery and JavaScript on clients, Java or .NET on servers, etc.

It's common to write web services in Java or .NET.  It shouldn't bother anyone to mix and match.

Use the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad idea. As a matter of fact, it's often a necessity. Especially with the two language you've mentioned. It's often necessary to have a client-side language, and then a separate server-side language. They have different purposes and they're both needed.

As for passing data between them, it's generally not a good idea to mix languages if you need to pass data between them. I'd need more information on the situation to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you can't reuse code as easily. This means for example that you might have to duplicate things like the ORM mapping for each language you are using.

Comment: Reuse is overrated, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "it depends", but in general there's nothing wrong with it, no.

Many times it's beneficial to actually do so for ease of development and maintenance since some languages are just simply suited towards certain tasks.

Other times, there's a communication barrier between languages depending on the data you're handling that's awkward.

And yet other times, you actually end up making your own separate languages (e.g. configuration files) because you simply don't like the available programming languages for a task.

Answer (score 0):

Your general question is a bit vague, as it's unclear what you're trying to do specifically.  However, if you're simply trying to get programs written in different languages to communicate to each other, you should consider an RPC library.

Thrift, originally developed by Facebook, is one potential (and pretty good IMO) option: http://thrift.apache.org/